# Aligning SideMenu on CodenameOne Toolbar to the right

Tags: codenameone

By default, Codename One Toolbar SideMenu (hamburger icon) is on the left of the title area, is it possible to have it on the right instead?

Comment: This is covered in this blog post: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top.html